# syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I cloned a project from https://github.com/iluminar/goodwork, and when doing composer install it show error said

```
ParseError

  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

  at C:\Users\Vysco Zyza\Videos\goodwork\app\Base\Utilities\ExtendedLivewireComponentsFinder.php:40
     36▕     }
     37▕
     38▕     protected function getName($class)
     39▕     {
  ➜  40▕         $classNamespace = collect(config('livewire.class_namespaces'))->filter(fn ($x) => strpos($class, $x) !== false)->first();
     41▕         $namespace = collect(explode('.', str_replace(['/', '\\'], '.', $classNamespace)))
     42▕             ->map([Str::class, 'kebab'])
     43▕             ->implode('.');
     44▕

  1   C:\Users\Vysco Zyza\Videos\goodwork\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322
      Composer\Autoload\includeFile("C:\Users\Vysco Zyza\Videos\goodwork\vendor\composer/../../app/Base/Utilities/ExtendedLivewireComponentsFinder.php")

  2   [internal]:0
      Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass("App\Base\Utilities\ExtendedLivewireComponentsFinder")
Script @php artisan livewire:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

what should I do?

Comment: this is syntax error, happened in ExtendedLivewireComponentsFinder line 322, you can share this class so we can help you

Comment: Is your PHP version 7.4? If not, that could be the problem.

Comment: Here is the code https://github.com/iluminar/goodwork/blob/master/app/Base/Utilities/ExtendedLivewireComponentsFinder.php

Comment: @Kameam what is your php version?

Comment: maybe u right, my when doing php -v it show  PHP 7.3.11, how to update it? @GertB.

Comment: It's because your php version is less than 7.4. Arrow functions were introduced in php 7.4 and this line use arrow functions. upgrading depends on your os

Comment: Arrow functions are new in PHP 7.4, in 7.3.11 they don't work. The update of php is different for every system, I don't really know how you update PHP on windows :-) google is your friend :-)

Comment: Aight, thanks mate

Comment: Glad i could help. :-)